# Batch: Find substring with quotes in string

Tags: batch-file, substring, quotes

I cannot get this to work. I am reading an XML file line by line and then look at each line if it contains a specific tag *<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction" version"*. When I find it, I would modify it and write everything back into a file.
However, I can not find the tag since it contains quote marks.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
....some more code....
SET dllFile=%DestPath%\%ProjectName%.dll.manifest

IF NOT EXIST "%dllFile%" (
   ECHO File %ProjectName%.dll.manifest does not exist^^!
   GOTO ERROR
) ELSE (
   ECHO Modifying %ProjectName%.dll.manifest in directory:
   ECHO %DestPath%

   REM Create a temporary file in the folder, where this batch file is being executed from
   >"temp.xml" (
      FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("%dllFile%") DO (
        SET "line=%%I"

        REM Insert existing line before modification
        SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
        ECHO %%I
        ENDLOCAL

        REM Find correct version number
        SET "myVariable=<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction" version"
        IF not "!line!"=="!line:myVariable=!" (
          echo !line!
        )
        ....some more code....
       )
    )
  )
```

Whatever escape characters I use, it will not find this particular line (or it finds every line). Everything else in above code works fine - only ***IF not "!line!"=="!line:myVariable=!"*** does not. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you assign interim variable `myVariable`?

Comment: That was my desperate attempt trying to fight the double quote issue in the IF statement...

Comment: I just discovered an `=`-sign in the search string, which is not possible since such separates search and replacement strings…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another method to compare the strings:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
; set "myvariable=<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction" version"
set myvariable
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  echo "%%a"|findstr /c:"!myvariable:"=\"!">nul && (
    echo DEBUG: found %%a
    REM do something special here
  ) || (
    echo %%a
    REM write line unchanged
  )
)
```

(you have to escape the doublequotes with `findstr;` findstr` uses the backslash as escape character)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up with

```
SET "xmlTag=<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ("%dllFile%") DO (
    ECHO "%%A"|FINDSTR /c:"!xmlTag:"=\"!">nul && (
        FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=^=" %%B IN ("%%A") DO (
        SET version=%%C
        SET version=!version:~0,-9!
        ECHO Found PostDeploymentAction.dll version number !version!
        )
    )
)
```

This gives me the version number I was after. The full XML line is `<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction" version="1.1.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />`. The first FOR loop gets the entire line out of the XML file, while the second FOR gets the actual version number "1.1.0.0".
The second FOR is a bit weird, but it works. However, I am sure there are better ways...

Comment: Maybe consider using a language that has a native method to read and write XML.  Jscript, Vbscript and Powershell are all scripting languages included with Windows that can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the above was a bit slow since FINDSTR is called for each line of the file (read file line by line and then analyze each line with FINDSTR).
There is a much, much faster version by calling FINDSTR only once for the entire file and then analyzing the return result found by FINDSTR.

```
SET "xmlTag=<assemblyIdentity name="PostDeploymentAction"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('FINDSTR /c:^"!xmlTag:"=\"!^" ^"%dllFile%^"') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=5 delims=^=^ " %%B IN ("%%A") DO (
       SET version=%%B
       ECHO Found PostDeploymentAction.dll version number !version:~1,-1!
    )
)
```